# What will happen to home partition if I reinstall ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, encryption, home-directory, reinstall, preinstallation

I decided to reinstall ubuntu because of  many problems that I can't fix. I have a home partition that is encrypted. If I reinstall ubuntu can I access to /home and how to do it.  I don't know the partition has been encrypted or the home directory but it was during installation that ubuntu asks to encrypte it.

Comment: You can tell the installer by using manual partitioning ("Something else" option) that it should use the `/home` partition for the installing system, but not format it. That way it will automatically set up fstab etc. to automount the partition at boot time. *This is the case for unencrypted partitions! I have no idea how it handles the encryption!*

Comment: **Before** you reinstall, you must record (write down, copy to USB key) the keys so the new system can mount and decrypt the partition. See `file:///usr/share/doc/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-faq.html#protectkey` on your system

Comment: @waltinator thanks for reply but can you andwer with complete guidance.

Comment: @Vesal75 No. It's up to you to read and learn. No one can provide step-by-step instructions that will 100% replace understanding.